# I don't understand this PDE solution involving Fourier coefficients and orthonormal eigenfunctions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, orthonormal, eigenfunctions

$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ with $x \in (0,\pi)$ and $y \in (0, \pi)$

Initial Conditions:

$$
u(x,0) = x^2
$$
$$
u(x,\pi) = 0
$$

Boundary conditions:

$$
u_{x}(0,y) = 0 = u_{x}(\pi, y)
$$

I performed separation of variables, which yielded $\frac{Y''}{Y} = \frac{-X''}{X} = \lambda$

From this we derive two ODE's:
$$
X'' + \lambda X = 0
$$

$$
Y'' - \lambda Y = 0
$$
For the first ODE, we know the general solution is $X(x) = A\sin(\sqrt \lambda x) + B\cos(\sqrt \lambda x)$
Using the boundary conditions I differentiated my general solution which yielded $X'(x) = \sqrt \lambda A \cos ( \sqrt \lambda x ) - \lambda B \sin (\sqrt \lambda x)$ or with the first boundary condition when $x = 0$, yields simply $X'(0) = \sqrt \lambda A = 0$ which tells us A = 0, right?

Well I am just having real trouble understanding what is the logic behind the [solution to this problem that my professor posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/505Pg.png). Where do the orthonormal eigenfunctions come from? Why is there no talk of solving for the constants that come out of the general solution? Where do the solutions for Y come from? I would really appreciate if someone could work through this problem step by step because I am really lost as to where the thinking comes to take the steps taken.

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well I am just having real trouble understanding what is the logic
>   behind the solution to this problem that my professor posted. Where do
>   the orthonormal eigenfunctions come from?

You are finding them by solving the $X$ problem, i.e. by finding all values of the parameter $\lambda$ for which there exists nontrivial solutions to the $X$ ODE and the $X$ boundary conditions. Note that you have only applied the BC at $x=0$. You need to apply the BC at $x=\pi$ to complete your analysis. Also, note that you have assumed $\lambda>0$ since you got sines and cosines for your general solution. Based on where it sounds you are in your understanding, you need to consider the cases $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda<0$ as well.

> Why is there no talk of
>   solving for the constants that come out of the general solution?

Well, you have to *have* the general solution (and $\lambda$ values) before you can do this. Once you find the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and eigenfunctions $X(x)$ (there will be an infinite sequence of each), *then* you can use the orthogonality of those eigenfunctions to determine the values of the constants in the general solution.

> Where do the solutions for Y come from?

Once $\lambda$ is known, you simply solve the $Y$ ODE for those $\lambda$ values.

---

Edit: A little more to help you along (for the $\lambda>0$ case)... $X(x)=A\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\implies X'(x)=A\sqrt{\lambda}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)-B\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$. Then $X'(0)=0\implies A\sqrt{\lambda}=0\implies A=0\text{ or }\sqrt{\lambda}=0\implies A=0$ since we are assuming $\lambda>0$.

On the other hand, $X'(\pi)=0\implies -B\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0\implies B=0, \sqrt{\lambda}=0,\text{ or }\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0$. If $B=0$, we already had $A=0$ so $X(x)=0$, but we were seeking nontrivial solutions. Also, $\sqrt{\lambda}=0$ is impossible since we are assuming $\lambda>0$. That leaves us with $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0\implies \sqrt{\lambda}=n\in\mathbb{Z}\implies \lambda=\lambda_n=n^2$, $n=1,2,\dots$ are the eigenvalues with associated eigenfunctions $X_n(x)=B_n\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x)=B_n\cos(nx)$, $n=1,2,\dots$

Now that the $\lambda_n$ are known, solve the $Y$ problem...

Comment: That's what I thought to, about analyzing the cases where $\lambda < 0$ and $\lambda = 0$ but why were these not analyzed in the solution posted? And I did do the case where $x = \pi$, which yields $\sqrt ( \lambda ) A \cos ((\sqrt \lambda \pi) )$

Comment: I just added some to help you along...

Comment: Thank you. Are you familiar with H.F. Weinberger's textbook on partial differential equations? I decided that I would be best served to go through some more elementary examples or else this is just an exercise in pretending to know what to do to proceed.

Comment: Yes, I know the book well. Your plan is a good one.

Comment: On the bottom of page 64 we test the case of $\lambda < 0$, and he says "the condition X(0) = 0 tells us that X(x) must be a multiple of $\sinh (\sqrt(- \lambda) x)$ ", but previously had defined the general solution of the case where $\lambda < 0$ as $X(x) = \exp{(\pm \sqrt (- \lambda) x)} \cos (\sqrt - \lambda y) + \exp{(\pm \sqrt (- \lambda) x)} \sin (\sqrt - \lambda y)$. When you substitute $x = 0$ into this equation, I believe that $X(0) = cos(\sqrt(- \lambda) y) + sin((\sqrt - \lambda) y)$, which I don't see how is related to $\sinh ((\sqrt - \lambda) x) $ ?

Comment: He also does the same thing on the next page, for $\lambda > 0$, "X must be a multiple of $\sin \sqrt (\lambda \pi)$." Where are these "must be" statements coming from? I just really don't see that hyperbolic one in my above comment.

Comment: Suppose $\lambda<0$. Then $X''+\lambda X=0\implies X''-\alpha^2 X=0$ for $\lambda=-\alpha^2<0$. The general solution to this is $X(x)=A\cosh(\alpha x)+B\sinh(\alpha x)$. Apply the BCs and you will see $A=B=0$. Thus, there are no negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Okay that makes sense... however I don't see how the statement "if $\lambda < 0$ the condition $X(0) = 0$ tells us that $X(x)$ must be a multiple of $sinh(\sqrt(- \lambda)x)$ because if you have $x = 0$, that only leaves you with $X(0) = \cos(\sqrt(- \lambda) y) + \sin(\sqrt(- \lambda) y)$, something in terms of y. I don't see how this result in terms of y "must be a multiple of" $\sinh(\sqrt(- \lambda) x)$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11730/discussion-between-pterodactyl-and-johnd)

Comment: I figured it out, thank you.